# How to implement N-Dimensional Convolution in TensorFlow / Keras? (with N > 3)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolution

I had an idea for a model that requires **multidimensional convolution** (i.e. 4D or more). However, I can't find anything higher than 3D Conv on the TF 2.0 / Keras module.

Is there a way to implement multimensional, ND Conv? (N > 3)